# Remove object from array when attribute 0 or below - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a controller that lets a user edit an object. Part of this decrements an attribute of the object – the quantity of my model. When the model's quantity reaches 0 or below, ideally I'd like to delete the whole object.

#### HTML

```
<div ng-app='basket'>
  <div ng-controller='BasketController as basket'>
    <div class='product' ng-repeat='product in cart.products'>{{ product.name }} Count: {{ product.quantity }} <a ng-click='product.quantity = product.quantity - 1'>Remove</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module('basket', []);
  var cart;

  app.controller('BasketController', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.getTimes=function(n){
      return new Array(n);
    };
    $scope.cart = {};
    $scope.cart.products = [{
      'name':'item 1',
      'quantity':3
    },{
      'name':'item 2',
      'quantity':3
    },{
      'name':'item 3',
      'quantity':3
    }];
  });

})();
```

#### Live demo

http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/bNBmXm

So for instance, in the above if you click 'remove' again and again on the first object, when you get to 0 I'd like to just have an array like the following:

```
    $scope.cart.products = [{
      'name':'item 2',
      'quantity':3
    },{
      'name':'item 3',
      'quantity':3
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just write a remove method to check for quantity and remove the item from the list.

In your controller:-

```
$scope.remove = function(product){
  var products = $scope.cart.products;
  product.quantity -= 1;

  if(!product.quantity){
    /*Splice the object from the array based on the index*/
    products.splice(products.indexOf(product), 1);
  }
}
```

and on click just call it as:

```
<a ng-click='remove(product)'>Remove</a>
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNoqwx)**

Comment: This was exactly what I was after. As a newcomer to angular I sometimes get a bit mixed up over what bits belong inline and which bits work way better in my js files

Comment: @Djave All the best!! btw did you mean to use controller As syntax ans still putting things directly on scope?

Answer (score 0):

Change your link to:

```
<a ng-click='remove(product)'>Remove</a>
```

And add the following method to the controller:

```
$scope.remove = remove;

function remove(product) {
    $scope.cart.products.splice($scope.cart.products.indexOf(product), 1);
}
```

Comment: Almost same as my answer. But you missed the part `When the model's quantity reaches 0 or below, ideally I'd like to delete the whole object.`

Comment: Yea you are right. Hadn't seen your answer yet when typing mine. No need to correct my answer anymore I guess :)